# Comparing encrypted values of same set of characters

Tags: mysql, linux, shell

If I encrypt a string twice and compare them, will they be the same?I'm doing this in MySQL to compare my plain password to the one that's encrypted and saved

Comment: You mean double encrypt a string and compare it with the original plain string or encrypt the plain string and compare with the original encrypted one?

Comment: i mean **encrypt the plain string and compare with the original encrypted one**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you are using the *same standard encryption algorithm* and the *same encryption key* for a particular input string you will always get the same encrypted output. It wouldn't make much sense if you get different outputs because then decryption would be an almost impossible task.